# How to tell if someone else is using the database?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I suspect this is an easy one that I don't know the answer to.
I have an Access 2010 database that is used by a number of different people, often at the same time.
I want, using VBA, to find out if somebody else is using the database when I am.
Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This sample sub, which uses a provider-specific schema, will list users. You need to pass a valid connection, for example:

```
ADOUserList Currentproject.Connection

  Public Sub ADOUserList(oConn As ADODB.Connection)
  Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
      Set rs = oConn.OpenSchema(adSchemaProviderSpecific, , _
          "{947bb102-5d43-11d1-bdbf-00c04fb92675}")
      Debug.Print rs.GetString
      rs.Close
  End Sub
```

The fields returned are:

```
COMPUTER_NAME
LOGIN_NAME
CONNECTED
SUSPECT_STATE
```

please note using `CurrentProject.Connection` is the only way to get the user list without locking the database. This technique still has the shortcoming that typically Access opens with the `LOGIN_NAME` admin. I've always had to match the COMPUTER_NAME to a login table to get the Windows username - it's a shortcoming of Access.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response. I'm getting an runtime error on the set rs line.  Says "Object or provider is not capable of performing requested operation" Any ideas?

Comment: please refer to this link for that issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477778/find-users-logged-into-access-database-using-powershell